# Creating a numpy array of 3D coordinates from three 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Suppose I have three arbitrary 1D arrays, for example:

```
x_p = np.array((1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0))
y_p = np.array((2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
z_p = np.array((8.0, 9.0))
```

These three arrays represent sampling intervals in a 3D grid, and I want to construct a 1D array of three-dimensional vectors for all intersections, something like

```
points = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 8.0],
                   [1.0, 2.0, 9.0],
                   [1.0, 3.0, 8.0],
                   ...
                   [5.0, 4.0, 9.0]])
```

Order doesn't actually matter for this. The obvious way to generate them:

```
npoints = len(x_p) * len(y_p) * len(z_p)
points = np.zeros((npoints, 3))
i = 0
for x in x_p:
    for y in y_p:
        for z in z_p:
            points[i, :] = (x, y, z)
            i += 1
```

So the question is... is there a faster way? I have looked but not found (possibly just failed to find the right Google keywords).

I am currently using this:

```
npoints = len(x_p) * len(y_p) * len(z_p)
points = np.zeros((npoints, 3))
i = 0
nz = len(z_p)
for x in x_p:
    for y in y_p:
        points[i:i+nz, 0] = x
        points[i:i+nz, 1] = y
        points[i:i+nz, 2] = z_p
        i += nz
```

but I feel like I am missing some clever fancy Numpy way?

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate; it is a similar question, but (obviously I am biased) I think my question is a simpler phrasing of a more general problem. I also think the answer on this question is better; use of meshgrid seems to be the simplest, fastest solution.

Comment: Also, the extension from 2D to 3D is non-obvious in my opinion.  Seeing that the answers have similar structures implies that the straight-forward extensions are a good start, but, *a priori*, it wasn't clear that these would work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use numpy mesh grid on the above example the following will work:

```
np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x_p,y_p,z_p)).reshape(3,-1).T
```

Numpy meshgrid for grids of more then two dimensions require numpy 1.7. To circumvent this and pulling the relevant data from the [source code](http://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py).

```
def ndmesh(*xi,**kwargs):
    if len(xi) < 2:
        msg = 'meshgrid() takes 2 or more arguments (%d given)' % int(len(xi) > 0)
        raise ValueError(msg)

    args = np.atleast_1d(*xi)
    ndim = len(args)
    copy_ = kwargs.get('copy', True)

    s0 = (1,) * ndim
    output = [x.reshape(s0[:i] + (-1,) + s0[i + 1::]) for i, x in enumerate(args)]

    shape = [x.size for x in output]

    # Return the full N-D matrix (not only the 1-D vector)
    if copy_:
        mult_fact = np.ones(shape, dtype=int)
        return [x * mult_fact for x in output]
    else:
        return np.broadcast_arrays(*output)
```

Checking the result:

```
print np.vstack((ndmesh(x_p,y_p,z_p))).reshape(3,-1).T

[[ 1.  2.  8.]
 [ 1.  2.  9.]
 [ 1.  3.  8.]
 ....
 [ 5.  3.  9.]
 [ 5.  4.  8.]
 [ 5.  4.  9.]]
```

For the above example:

```
%timeit sol2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 56.1 us per loop

%timeit np.vstack((ndmesh(x_p,y_p,z_p))).reshape(3,-1).T
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.1 us per loop
```

For when each dimension is 100:

```
%timeit sol2()
1 loops, best of 3: 655 ms per loop
In [10]:

%timeit points = np.vstack((ndmesh(x_p,y_p,z_p))).reshape(3,-1).T
10 loops, best of 3: 21.8 ms per loop
```

Depending on what you want to do with the data, you can return a view:

```
%timeit np.vstack((ndmesh(x_p,y_p,z_p,copy=False))).reshape(3,-1).T
100 loops, best of 3: 8.16 ms per loop
```

Comment: Fortunately I have Numpy 1.7. For my particular case where the dimensions will probably be at least 128, and can be more (large data sets), the mgrid/meshgrid solution seems to work best and is slightly cleaner than my original two-for-loop solution.

Comment: As a note, if you are not using sparse arrays `ndmesh` is equivalent to `np.meshgrid` so all the timings and keywords will be identical.

Answer (score 7):

For your specific example, [`mgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) is quite useful.:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: points = np.mgrid[1:6, 2:5, 8:10]
In [3]: points.reshape(3, -1).T
Out[3]:
array([[1, 2, 8],
       [1, 2, 9],
       [1, 3, 8],
       [1, 3, 9],
       [1, 4, 8],
       [1, 4, 9],
       [2, 2, 8],
       [2, 2, 9],
       [2, 3, 8],
       [2, 3, 9],
       [2, 4, 8],
       [2, 4, 9],
       [3, 2, 8],
       [3, 2, 9],
       [3, 3, 8],
       [3, 3, 9],
       [3, 4, 8],
       [3, 4, 9],
       [4, 2, 8],
       [4, 2, 9],
       [4, 3, 8],
       [4, 3, 9],
       [4, 4, 8],
       [4, 4, 9],
       [5, 2, 8],
       [5, 2, 9],
       [5, 3, 8],
       [5, 3, 9],
       [5, 4, 8],
       [5, 4, 9]])
```

More generally, if you have specific arrays that you want to do this with, you'd use [`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) instead of `mgrid`. However, you'll need numpy 1.7 or later for it to work in more than two dimensions.

Comment: Specifically with meshgrid in numpy 1.7: `np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x_p,y_p,z_p)).reshape(3,-1).T`

Comment: This works well for me, even with large grids. I had intended to write the question to not assume that the spacings were even; actually in my case they are but I think for the sake of generality the meshgrid solution is the best answer for this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
def sol1():
    points = np.array( list(product(x_p, y_p, z_p)) )
```

Another solution using iterators and `np.take` showed to be about 3X faster for your case:

```
from itertools import izip, product

def sol2():
    points = np.empty((len(x_p)*len(y_p)*len(z_p),3))

    xi,yi,zi = izip(*product( xrange(len(x_p)),
                              xrange(len(y_p)),
                              xrange(len(z_p))  ))

    points[:,0] = np.take(x_p,xi)
    points[:,1] = np.take(y_p,yi)
    points[:,2] = np.take(z_p,zi)
    return points
```

Timing results:

```
In [3]: timeit sol1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop

In [4]: timeit sol2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.9 µs per loop

In [6]: timeit ops()
10000 loops, best of 3: 59 µs per loop

In [11]: timeit joekingtons() # with your permission Joe...
10000 loops, best of 3: 56.2 µs per loop
```

So, only my second solution and Joe Kington's solution would give you some performance gain...

Comment: According to my timings, your second solution runs in 66% of the time of the OP's solution with the preallocation, which runs almost as fast as the mgrid solution. Perhaps you should show timings? You can also shave of a little time by using np.empty instead of np.zeros

Comment: This is fine for small systems, however it scales very poorly. For such systems its likely much better to take the (14 microsecond!) performance penalty for cleaner code. Nd meshgrid is consistently faster across all sizes and can be easily used by copy/pasting the numpy source code.

Comment: @Ophion The problem would be if in `x_p, y_p or z_p` you had some non-integer values irregularly spaced like `np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 1., 2., 3.])` and so forth...

Comment: @Saullo Castro meshgrid takes this into account.

Comment: When I tried this (albeit not in a particularly good way, only doing a few repeats) with timeit with three arrays of 256 each, it took a bit longer than a minute; faster than the naive for loop method (over two minutes) but slower than the faster for loop method which only looped over x_p and y_p; that took about 20-30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For those who had to stay with numpy <1.7.x, here is a simple two-liner solution:

```
g_p=np.zeros((x_p.size, y_p.size, z_p.size))
array_you_want=array(zip(*[item.flatten() for item in \
                                 [g_p+x_p[...,np.newaxis,np.newaxis],\
                                  g_p+y_p[...,np.newaxis],\
                                  g_p+z_p]]))
```

Very easy to expand to even higher dimenision as well.
Cheers!