# Creating a numpy array of 3D coordinates from three 1D arrays, first index changing fastest

Tags: python, numpy

similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253210/creating-a-numpy-array-of-3d-coordinates-from-three-1d-arrays)
I have three arbitrary 1D arrays, for example:

```
x_p = np.array((0.0,1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4))
y_p = np.array((5.5,6.6,7.7))
z_p = np.array((8.8, 9.9))
```

I need

```
points = np.array([[0.0, 5.5, 8.8],
                   [1.1, 5.5, 8.8],
                   [2.2, 5.5, 8.8],
                   ...
                   [4.4, 7.7, 9.9]])
```

1) with the first index changing fastest.2) points are float coordinates, not integer index.
3) I noticed from version 1.7.0, numpy.meshgrid has changed  behavior with default `indexing='xy'` and need to use

`np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x_p,y_p,z_p,indexing='ij')).reshape(3,-1).T`

to get the result points with last index changing fast, which is not I want.(It was mentioned only from 1.7.0,`meshgrid` supports dimension>2, I didn't check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this with some trial and error.

I think the `ij` v `xy` indexing has been in `meshgrid` forever (it's the `sparse` parameter that's newer). It just affects the order of the 3 returned elements.

To get `x_p` varying fastest I put it last in the argument list, and then used a `::-1` to reverse column order at the end.

I used `stack` to join the arrays on a new axis at the end, so I don't need to transpose.  But the reshaping and transpose's are all cheap (time wise).  So they can be used in any combination that works and is understandable.

```
In [100]: np.stack(np.meshgrid(z_p, y_p, x_p, indexing='ij'),3).reshape(-1,3)[:,::-1]
Out[100]: 
array([[ 0. ,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 1.1,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 2.2,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 3.3,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 4.4,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 0. ,  6.6,  8.8],
       ...
       [ 2.2,  7.7,  9.9],
       [ 3.3,  7.7,  9.9],
       [ 4.4,  7.7,  9.9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might permute axes with `np.transpose` to achieve the output in that desired format -

```
np.array(np.meshgrid(x_p, y_p, z_p)).transpose(3,1,2,0).reshape(-1,3)
```

Sample output -

```
In [104]: np.array(np.meshgrid(x_p, y_p, z_p)).transpose(3,1,2,0).reshape(-1,3)
Out[104]: 
array([[ 0. ,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 1.1,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 2.2,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 3.3,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 4.4,  5.5,  8.8],
       [ 0. ,  6.6,  8.8],
       [ 1.1,  6.6,  8.8],
       [ 2.2,  6.6,  8.8],
       [ 3.3,  6.6,  8.8],
       [ 4.4,  6.6,  8.8],
       [ 0. ,  7.7,  8.8],
       [ 1.1,  7.7,  8.8],
       ....
       [ 3.3,  7.7,  9.9],
       [ 4.4,  7.7,  9.9]])
```