# Create Numpy Grid in correct order

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have several arrays with points along my x-, y-,...-axes and want to create a grid with all points in it like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [20, 40, 60, 80]
result = []
for xi in x:
    for yi in y:
        result.append([xi, yi])
np.array(result)
```

which gives me

```
array([[ 1, 20],
       [ 1, 40],
       [ 1, 60],
       [ 1, 80],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 2, 40],
       [ 2, 60],
       [ 2, 80],
       [ 3, 20],
       [ 3, 40],
       [ 3, 60],
       [ 3, 80]])
```

To do this with numpy I found the following code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253210/creating-a-numpy-array-of-3d-coordinates-from-three-1d-arrays) question:

```
np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x, y)).reshape(2, -1).T
```

But this gives the result in the wrong order:

```
array([[ 1, 20],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 20],
       [ 1, 40],
       [ 2, 40],
       [ 3, 40],
       [ 1, 60],
       [ 2, 60],
       [ 3, 60],
       [ 1, 80],
       [ 2, 80],
       [ 3, 80]])
```

It goes through the x-values first, then y-values.

I can get around this by using

```
np.vstack(reversed(np.meshgrid(y, x))).reshape(2, -1).T
```

but this does not work any more in 3D, where

```
np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z)).reshape(3, -1).T
```

goes through z-values first, then x-values, then y-values.

**How can I get the correct order in all dimensions with numpy?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the matrix indexing `ij` in `np.meshgrid` as the `indexing` parameter to get the reversed order, by default it's the *cartesian* indexing order `xy`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [20, 40, 60, 80]

np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij'), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)
#array([[ 1, 20],
#       [ 1, 40],
#       [ 1, 60],
#       [ 1, 80],
#       [ 2, 20],
#       [ 2, 40],
#       [ 2, 60],
#       [ 2, 80],
#       [ 3, 20],
#       [ 3, 40],
#       [ 3, 60],
#       [ 3, 80]])
```

---

In 3d this could be:

```
np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij'), axis=-1).reshape(-1, 3)
```