# How to generate a 3D array of data based on a 1D array of data and three 1D arrays of spatial coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation

I have 3D scattered data that I need to interpolate. My chosen interpolation method requires inputs of (x,y,z,v) where:

(x,y,z) spatial coordinates of original grid (1D or 3D arrays)
(v)     values of data (must be 3D array)

I currently have four 1D arrays for x,y,z, and v with lengths of L=5000 for 5000 unique data points.

Using the solution provided here,

[Creating a numpy array of 3D coordinates from three 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253210/creating-a-numpy-array-of-3d-coordinates-from-three-1d-arrays)

Numpy.meshgrid produces 3D arrays for each coordinate direction with 1.25 × 10^11 elements. I run out of memory using this approach.

Is there another method to map my 1D array of values, v, to a 3D array with the appropriate size of 5000 elements?