3D parameter vectors multiplication appending with python?
I have to make a parameter optimization in 3 independent variables.
Each variable goes from 1 to 10 (or 0 to 9), and I want a 3D matrix of all possible combinations.
For simplicity, making shorter example of 1 to 3 (in integer steps).
Using Python,
I am thinking:
    A = [a1, a2, a3]
    B = [b1, b2, b3]
    C = [c1, c2, c3]

What is the function (f) that produce a 3D matrix with elements (ai, bj, ck) for all elements?
    A (f) B (f) C = {[(a1, b1, c1) (a1, b2, c1) (a1, b2, c1), (a2, b1, c1) (a2, b2, c1) (a2, b2, c1), (a3, b1, c1) (a3, b2, c1) (a3, b2, c1)],
                     [(a1, b1, c2) (a1, b2, c2) (a1, b2, c2), (a2, b1, c2) (a2, b2, c2) (a2, b2, c2), (a3, b1, c2) (a3, b2, c2) (a3, b2, c2)],
                     [(a1, b1, c3) (a1, b2, c3) (a1, b2, c3), (a2, b1, c3) (a2, b2, c3) (a2, b2, c3), (a3, b1, c3) (a3, b2, c3) (a3, b2, c3)]}
    
    import numpy as np
    Min_p = -100
    Max_p = 100
    
    MaC_dim = 3
    PrC_dim = 3
    PoC_dim = 3
    
    Main_cursor = np.linspace(Min_p, Max_p, MaC_dim)
    Pre__cursor = np.linspace(Min_p, Max_p, PrC_dim)
    Post_cursor = np.linspace(Min_p, Max_p, PoC_dim)
    array_3D = {}
    
    for x in Main_cursor:
      for y in Pre__cursor:
          for z in Post_cursor:
              array_3D[x, y, z] = [x, y, z]
              print(x, y, z)
    
    #send command for x,y,z as MainC, PreC, PostC as parameters
    #read command of single result
    #store command on matrix generated of results

    print(array_3D)

Why my last command gives that garbage output?

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253210/creating-a-numpy-array-of-3d-coordinates-from-three-1d-arrays help?
